# How can you have multiple colours in a single lore line?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a long description of an item, with multiple colours:

```
give @p leather_chestplate{display:{Lore:'[{"text":"It is","color":"gray"},{"text":" SUPREME","color":"light_purple"}]'}}
```

With all of my past trials, either `SUPREME` is on the next line, or it doesn't work. Why isn't it working and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are *so close*! You are almost correct in that you're trying to put the `Lore` tag as a single string so that it will appear in one line, but you forgot that the `Lore` tag is a list by default, in case additional lines need to be added. Even if you are only planning to have one line, the `Lore` tag still has to be a List tag.

Incorrect way:

```
{
  display: {
    Lore: '[{"text":"It is","color":"gray"},{"text":" SUPREME","color":"light_purple"}]'
  }
}
```

Correct way:

```
{
  display: {
    Lore: [
      '[{"text":"It is","color":"gray"},{"text":" SUPREME","color":"light_purple"}]'
    ]
  }
}
```